# ConstraintLayout 2.0 rendering problems

Tags: android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout, android-studio-4.0

After updating to ConstraintLayout 2.0 I realized that even the simplest layouts can not be previewed properly in Android Studio, both on OS X and Ubuntu.

First, my setup looks like this: I'm using `"androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0"`, the version of Android Studio is 4.0.1 (the latest stable release) on both of my computers, the version of Android Gradle plugin is 4.0.1, the version of Gradle is 6.1.1.

Here's an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I would expect it to draw the TextView aligned to the top of the screen.

What I end up seeing instead is this:

[image]

I tried turning off the experimental rendering engine as AS warned me there might be some issues with it but to no avail.

Is there something obvious I might be missing? Since 2.0.0 was in release for 2-3 days (and the release candidate was available for a wide audience for longer than that), I assume all obvious glitches should've been resolved at this point.

**Upd.** AS states there is a following rendering problem:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams$Table
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(ConstraintLayout.java:2603)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.generateLayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.java:1823)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.generateLayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.java:481)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1125)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1097)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:501)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:348)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:404)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:141)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:678)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$8(RenderTask.java:809)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1604)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**Upd. 2** I've submitted a [bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/166042810), let's see if this is a bug with Android Studio / Constraint Layout indeed (which I think is not the case).

Comment: Seems like bug. Create an issue.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Ok, in my case this definitely looks like an issue with a project cache. Once I've cleaned it up (Build -> Clean Project), the layout preview started working just fine.

Comment: Clean Project did the job for me too

Comment: Clear cache and then restart + Clean Project worked for me

Comment: I'm also facing the rendering problem with latest dependency  androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4. 
Getting 2 rednering errors "Path.op() not supported " & 
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657) + such 20 lines

Tried gradle syncing, invalidating cache & restart but it couldn't fixed it.

Comment: Oh my my.. this absolutely was the case! How would one know. Thank you to yourself and Google.

Answer (score 4):

I am having the same issue after updating to 2.0.0, I believe this is an AS/Constraint Layout issue. Using version 1.1.3, for the time being, works just fine.

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```

Comment: I also tried restarting AS, cleaning cache and nothing seemed to work, up until returning to version 1.1.3

Comment: Also, release 2.0.1 fixed my issues, maybe it was a different one.

Comment: Migrating to a newest version of ConstraintLayout dependency worked for me :)